# Change inactive tab header font color

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, tabcontrol, mahapps.metro

I am using MahApps.Metro tab control. I want to know if it is possible to change the font color of header text when the tab is inactive.

Currently it is like this:
[image]

I can change the active tab font color by using:

```
        <Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush" Color="Red"/>
        </Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl.Resources>
```

[image]

But i am not able to change the color for inactive tabs. I want to change the grey color to some other color; for instance lets say green. Is it possible to change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*MahApps.Metro* `TabItem` [template](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.TabControl.xaml) uses a dynamic resource with `"GrayNormalBrush"` key as the font color when it's inactive. So all you need to do is to supply a `Brush` of your liking as a resource with that key. Depending on the scope of the change you want to make you have to pick a proper place to put your brush.

**Changing a single `TabItem`**

To change the inactive brush on a single `TabItem`, put the brush in its resources dictionary:

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Resource>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayNormalBrush" Color="Red" />
    </TabItem.Resources>
</TabItem>
```

**Changing all `TabItem`s within a single `TabControl`**

To modify all `TabItem`s within a `TabControl` you should override the `TabItem`'s default style, put the brush in its resources dictionary, and put that style as a `TabControl`'s resource:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <!-- It's important to set the BasedOn property so that we
             override the style rather than redefine it -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayNormalBrush" Color="Red" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

You could also move the style up the hierarchy to widen its scope, e.g. if you put that style as a `Window`'s resource, all `TabItem`s within that window would be modified.

**Changing all `TabItem`s across the whole application**

This part proved to be a little trickier than just putting that style in *App.xaml* resources dictionary. Key thing here is that this style should be defined **after** the *MahApps.Metro* one is referenced. In my case, when I had *MahApps.Metro* dictionaries references in *App.xaml* and also put that style there, the first `TabItem` was not styled **at all**, whereas the following ones were fine and dandy.

The trick was to create a dictionary in a separate file, say *Resources.xaml*, put that style there, and reference that dictionary from *App.xaml*. Note that the order in which the dictionaries are referenced is crucial for this solution to work:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml" />
            ...
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped. Is it also possible to make other changes to the font? Like make the header font of the selected tab bold. I tried using <Style.Triggers/> but that changes the font of the tab content not the tab header font.

Comment: @ilmenite you can do controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontWeight="Bold" on the MetroTabItem to bold.

Comment: @JMIII Could you specify what your `controls` namespace resolves to?

Comment: @Grx70 sure xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"

Comment: @Grx70 this is not working for me, can you please help.